# In a text based browser game, how would I make a typewriter effect in the dialogue?

Tags: html, css

In a text based browser game, how would I make the text kind of like into a typewriter effect in the dialogue box like games such as Animal Crossing and Pokemon?
This would be my first project done on my own terms, and I'm just not sure how to make an effect like that, or what language even. I plan to code this all in HTML, CSS, and whatever I need to make the dialogue do that effect. 
Thank you!

Comment: When posting a question here, you need to provide the relevant bits of code.  In this case, we need your HTML (just the relevant bits) and the CSS you have / may be trying.  What's even better is to set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for us to see / test on.  (Note you can get a close effect with css, a very exact effect with jQuery).

Comment: Heres a good javascript plugin you could leverage: http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

Comment: Your question title says "text crawl into the dialogue box" (???) and your actual question says typewriter effect. Can you clarify which one?

Comment: Edited, I meant typewriter. I will post bits of code when they're completed, so far this is all only simply an idea. More or less, I wanted to know what languages I'd need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean like this?

```js
var str = 'this is a typewriter effect';
var interval;
var index = 0;

interval = setInterval(typewriter, 200);

function typewriter() {
  if (index >= str.length) {

    clearInterval(interval);
  } else {
    $('#bla').append(str[index]);

    index++;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='bla'></div>
```